# gRPC failure detection in Golang

Tags: go, grpc-go

I am trying to use https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#ClientConn.WaitForStateChange function to implement a failure detection mechanism. I noticed when I stop the server the state of the gRPC connection goes from READY to IDLE.  However, I expect it goes to TransientFailure state. I also tried to set keep alive parameters but it doesn't seem there is a change in that behavior. Any ideas what could causing this behavior?

Consider that If I make a call after the server down, I will see TransientFailure state change otherwise what I see is just IDLE state.

Comment: The document below lists all states and their transitions. I'm not sure what your server and client configuration settings are, but I'll guess they are the default ones. When you make a call after a server is down, it makes sense that you get a TransientFailure state because TCP 3-way handshake is timing out. Regarding the Idle state, it would be beneficial to check (not sure how) if the server is sending the GOAWAY signal to the client because that can be the cause of the Idle state.
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/connectivity-semantics-and-api.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDLE is the correct next state, here.  If any new RPCs are sent, the client will attempt to connect, at which point it will go to CONNECTING and then TRANSIENT_FAILURE.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger the state change without any RPC calls?

Comment: Yes: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#ClientConn.Connect